# Using masonry JS for my code

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-masonry

I've tried applying the Masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/ JS to make the images float under each other but it doesn't seem to work.

I've used the following function - what have I done wrong? CSS issue maybe?

```
<script>
  $(function(){

    $('.cycler-wrap').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.cycler-container',
      columnWidth: 100
    });

  });
</script>
```

Updated the site as per Kelvin's response below. Now just a cycle issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is your `.cycle-container` elements are 0 pixels high, because your `img` elements are absolutely positioned, which takes them out of the document's flow.

If you make your `.cycler img` elements `position:relative` instead, masonry should work as expected. Since your images are `display:inline`, to keep cycler working you actually only need to make the first image `position:relative`:

```
.cycler img{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.cycler img:first-child{
    position:relative;
}
```

Of course, not all browsers support `:first-child`, so it might be better to just add a `.first` class to the first image in each group and use that as the selector instead.

Comment: Thanks kelvin. the `.cycler img` elements must be `position:absolute` due to the cycler. If I set it to relative, the fade in images are messed up.

Comment: Any other ideas Kelvin? Or should I throw up a version on jsFiddle?

Comment: Got you - it looks like you'll have to set the height of each `.cycler` element, then, by adding `style="height:123px"` to them. If this isn't an option, one final option could be to duplicate one of the `img`s in each cycler group, but give it a class that will cause it to be excluded from the cycler code, and give it `visibility:hidden`, which will make it invisible but still take up space in the dom. Messy, but it'll work...

Comment: Thanks Kelvin. If you check out the updated site, maybe you have a quick fix for making the cycler work again but with Masonry in place as it is? :) Thank you again!

Comment: Whoops - left a bit out, add `top:0;left:0;` to `.cycler img`

Comment: You're a genius!! One last question, if you visit the URL, how can I get the eggs image to be on the bottom left and the longer images to be to the right of it? That way it forms one big square of images :) Thank you again!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19250/discussion-between-dave-and-kelvin-mackay)